# How to Filter Out Today's Date in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
Company     Date                 Value
ABC         08/21/16 00:00:00    500
ABC         08/22/16 00:00:00    600
ABC         08/23/16 00:00:00    650
ABC         08/24/16 00:00:00    625
ABC         08/25/16 00:00:00    675
ABC         08/26/16 00:00:00    680
```

If we assume that 26-August-2016 is today's date, then I would like to create a new data frame that effectively excludes the data in the 08/26/16 row.

**EDIT:**
Here's my code to do so:

```
today = time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
df.Date = df.Date <> today
```

Unfortunately, I see an error message indicating:

```
'Series' object has no attribute 'Date'
```

Any idea how to resolve this?

Thanks!

**SOLUTION:**

```
today = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

df = df.loc[(df.Date < today)]
```

Comment: Your proposed input data and error output don't match, you state dataframe in your input but your error refers to a Series

Comment: can you post an output of `print(df.dtypes)`?

Comment: `df` is a Series, not a Dataframe. That's your error

Comment: @cricket_007 - I'm using df = pd.read_csv(myFileName) and then calling type(df), which returns "pandas.core.frame.DataFrame"

Comment: @MaxU - the output of print(df.dtypes) is: Company:object, Date: object, Value:int64

Comment: Have you tried `df['Date']`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want to filter the dates that appear earlier than your specified date, though the title seems misleading. You must convert the `Date` column which are of dtype `object` to `datetime64`.

```
In [22]: df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

In [23]: today = datetime.strptime('08/26/16', '%m/%d/%y')

In [24]: today
Out[24]: datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 26, 0, 0)

In [25]: df = df.loc[(df['Date'] < today)]

In [26]: df
Out[26]: 
  Company       Date  Value
0     ABC 2016-08-21    500
1     ABC 2016-08-22    600
2     ABC 2016-08-23    650
3     ABC 2016-08-24    625
4     ABC 2016-08-25    675
```

Comment: Today's date can be obtained with `datetime.now()` and assigned to `today` before the filter or use it inside the filter: `df = df.loc[(df['Date'] < datetime.now())]`